# GNU ld cannot find library which is there

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, ld, library-path

The packages I'm toying with here are rather unknown, but nevertheless the problem is rather generic. Basically, I'm trying to compile Python module (called rql) with C++ extension. The extension uses external framework called gecode, which contains several libraries. I compiled gecode and installed locally. Now, let the output speak for itself:

```
red@devel:~/build/rql-0.23.3$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/red/usr/lib
red@devel:~/build/rql-0.23.3$ ls $LD_LIBRARY_PATH | grep libgecodeint 
libgecodeint.so
libgecodeint.so.22
libgecodeint.so.22.0
red@devel:~/build/rql-0.23.3$ python setup.py build
running build
running build.py
package init file './test/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
running build_ext
building 'rql_solve' extension
g++ -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-i686-2.5/gecode-solver.o -lgecodeint -lgecodekernel -lgecodesearch -o build/lib.linux-i686-2.5/rql_solve.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgecodeint
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Is LD_LIBRARY_PATH exported in your environment?

Comment: Is the libgecodeint.so that is in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH for the right architecture (e.g. 32-bit or 64-bit as appropriate)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for runtime linker/loader (same effect could be achieved with [`ldconfig`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) ). What you need is the `-L` flag:

```
-L/home/red/usr/lib
```

on the compiler command line.

#### Edit:

And - thanks to @bjg for reminding me - you can use `LIBRARY_PATH` if you don't want to mess with compiler options.

Comment: Yes, I would mark his comment as answer if I could :)

It's kinda strange that ld doesn't look in it's runtime search path anyway, but the problem is solved now, so big thanks to you and others here!

Answer (score 1):

You've apparently modified `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to a non-standard location in your home directory. Do you know if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the environment used to call g++ in setup.py matches your shell's environment?

See if you can pass arguments to `setup.py` to modify the library path or simply pass `-L/home/red/usr/lib` to g++.

Comment: g++ will use `LIBRARY_PATH` if present so you could try `LIBRARY_PATH=/red/usr/lib python setup.py build`